# Describing the position of elements of a web page

Tags: prepositions, phrase-request, sentence-choice

Here is a screenshot of the [Visual Dictionary Online](http://visual.merriam-webster.com/) website's homepage as displayed in my browser:

[image]

My question is: **How would you refer to the position of the image of the reindeer on the web page?**

In this case, I don't want you to tell me the reindeer is "above the *Image of the Week* box", or "below the heron", etc.; i.e., I don't want its position expressed in relation to other elements of the web page; the only thing allowed for now is the page itself, which you may picture as a blank sheet of paper with our buddy Rudolph on it. I'm only insisting on this requirement because those (other) elements may not be present on other web pages.

I'd describe the position of the reindeer like this:

> 1a. The picture of the reindeer is **at the right side** of the web page.
>   1b. The picture of the reindeer is **on the right side** of the web page.
>   1c. The picture of the reindeer is **in the upper-right section/area/quadrant** of the web page.

---

The second question is regarding the position of the *Search* button, which is located just below the navigation bar, in the middle: **How would you describe the position of the *Search* button with respect to the *Google Custom Search* search field?**

My attempt:

> 2a. The *Search* button is (located) **to the right of the search field**.
>   2b. The *Search* button is **next to the search field, at the right**.
>   2c. The *Search* button is **next to the search field, on the right**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how specific you want to be. None of the sentences are grammatically incorrect, so the specificity is the only real difference between them.

With regards to **1a** and **1b**, they're basically equivalent. I think *on* sounds slightly better than *at*, but it wouldn't be a mistake to use *at* in this context. They both say the picture is on the right side of the page, but that doesn't specify its height on the right side. It could be right at the top, right at the bottom or anywhere in between. If you want to be specific, **1c** is the most so.

With the second set of sentences, **2a** is the least specific. Depending on the web page fluency of the person reading, they may know contextually that *Search* buttons are almost always directly next to their search fields. However, if they are not too fluent, that might not be clear with **2a**. Because of this, I would opt for **2b** or **2c**. Again, I think *on* sounds better, but either is fine.

Answer (score 2):

In idiomatic English, the audience being average native speakers with no knowledge of web-design terminology...

*Taking into account your direction to imagine the page as otherwise empty* (no banner, no columns, no other images or divisions):

> The reindeer picture is located **in the top right quadrant of the page** or **almost at the very top right of the page**.

Now for the search button:

> The search button is located **immediately to the right of** or **just to the right of** the Google Custom
>   Search box.

Answer (score 1):

To describe the portions of your layout example, you might use

> The reindeer is located at the top of the third column underneath the banner header and navigation bar.

In UI layout, the *last column* (third column in this case) is always on the right, and the reindeer is at the top of that column.

> The search box is just under the navigation bar at the top of the *middle column*.

For UI layout, you can use a grid system similar to **Bootstap** or **Foundation** where column define the horizontal locations on the page. The vertical locations are usually then determined by content which "*float*" within the columns.

The basic layout of the page is

> 1) header banner
>   2) navigation bar
>   3) search bar
>   4) three columns
>   4-a) top of first column is a an image search box, then a *theme  navigation sidebar* followed by social media links
>   4-b) middle column is the main body with examples and explanations
>   4-c) third column is the *advertising sidebar*